# How can one find a set of keywords in a document, all/some of them at a certain distance cutoff?

Tags: text, full-text-search, distance, libraries, keyword

I have a set of keywords, around 10. I want to perform a search within a very long document, and check whether I can find the set of keywords there, but not only their presence or existence on the text, also if all/some of them or a subset of them are situated at a distance cutoff of, for instance, 3 sentences, or 30 words or any other proximity metrics. How can one do this? I have just thought of writing some python code that finds one of the keywords, and then checks whether any other of the keywords is around 3 lines of text. But this would need a lot of computing power and it is inefficient.

Comment: Lucene can perform [proximity search](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Proximity_Searches).

Comment: but how can one apply what Lucene offers for finding 10 words using proximity criteria?

Comment: There is significant difference between finding windows with all words and windows with some words, they might even require different algorithms to have optimal performance. How long is "long", a few megabytes or tens of megabytes?

Comment: the ideal would be all the words, but let's say, we need to find the maximum number of words. Long can be hundreds of megabytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion to solve this, would be create a (Hash)Map, enter each word, as key, and add the location of the word, as value to a list, which is the value in the Map.

For the text *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog* this would result in a model, like given below (in json format).

**Remark:** Here all words are added to the index, as if they are written in lower-case.

```
{
    "document": [
        {
            "key": "the",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 1
                },
                {
                    "location": 7
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "quick",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "brown",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "fox",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "jumps",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "over",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "lazy",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "dog",
            "value": [
                {
                    "location": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 
}
```

Once this *index* is made, it's easy to see how far the different words are located from each other. As seen in the word *the*, which is located at location 1 and 7.

Also the number of times a word is shown in the text, can easily be gotten, by the number of locations, that are give for a word.

**TIP:** Add additonal location information, like which chapter / section / page etc.

Answer (score 3):

To determine if a set of keywords are within a given distance of each other inside of a larger document, you could use a sliding window with a length equal to the given distance and move it across the document.  As you move the window, keep track of each word that falls in and out of the window.  If the window ever contains all of the keywords, then the condition is satisfied.  This approach has a time complexity of `O(len(document))` and a memory complexity of `O(len(window))`.

The following is a sample implementation in Python of the approach described above:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sets import Set
def isInProximityWindow(doc, keywords, windowLen):
    words = doc.split()
    wordsLen = len(words)
    if (windowLen > wordsLen):
        windowLen = wordsLen

    keywordsLen = len(keywords)
    allKeywordLocs = defaultdict(Set)
    numKeywordsInWindow = 0
    locKeyword = {}
    for i in range(wordsLen):
        windowContents = sorted([k for k in allKeywordLocs.keys() if allKeywordLocs[k]])
        print "On beginning of iteration #%i, window contains '%s'" % (i, ','.join(windowContents))

        oldKeyword = locKeyword.pop(i-windowLen, None)
        if oldKeyword:
            keywordLocs = allKeywordLocs[oldKeyword]
            keywordLocs.remove(i-windowLen)
            if not keywordLocs:
                print "'%s' fell out of window" % oldKeyword
                numKeywordsInWindow -= 1
        word = words[i]
        print "Next word is '%s'" % word
        if word in keywords:
            locKeyword[i] = word
            keywordLocs = allKeywordLocs[word]
            if not keywordLocs:
                print "'%s' fell in window" % word
                numKeywordsInWindow += 1
                if numKeywordsInWindow == keywordsLen:
                    return True
            keywordLocs.add(i)
    return False
```

Sample output:

```
>>> isInProximityWindow("the brown cow jumped over the moon and the red fox jumped over the black dog", Set(["fox", "over", "the"]), 4)
On beginning of iteration #0, window contains ''
Next word is 'the'
'the' fell in window
On beginning of iteration #1, window contains 'the'
Next word is 'brown'
On beginning of iteration #2, window contains 'the'
Next word is 'cow'
On beginning of iteration #3, window contains 'the'
Next word is 'jumped'
On beginning of iteration #4, window contains 'the'
'the' fell out of window
Next word is 'over'
'over' fell in window
On beginning of iteration #5, window contains 'over'
Next word is 'the'
'the' fell in window
On beginning of iteration #6, window contains 'over,the'
Next word is 'moon'
On beginning of iteration #7, window contains 'over,the'
Next word is 'and'
On beginning of iteration #8, window contains 'over,the'
'over' fell out of window
Next word is 'the'
On beginning of iteration #9, window contains 'the'
Next word is 'red'
On beginning of iteration #10, window contains 'the'
Next word is 'fox'
'fox' fell in window
On beginning of iteration #11, window contains 'fox,the'
Next word is 'jumped'
On beginning of iteration #12, window contains 'fox,the'
'the' fell out of window
Next word is 'over'
'over' fell in window
On beginning of iteration #13, window contains 'fox,over'
Next word is 'the'
'the' fell in window
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I run some simple benchmarks under these conditions:

- Python 3.4 in Windows
- 150 distinct random words, length 5 - 16 characters
- 10 search terms, all must be found
- window length of 75
- iterated over 50 million words, about 514 million characters in total

Word generation:

```
def generator(gen_salt):
    words = [word(i) for i in range(n_distinct_words)]
    np.random.seed(123)

    for i in range(int(n_words)):
        yield words[np.random.randint(0, n_distinct_words)]
```

Search code, `words = generator, search_words = set, window_len = int`:

```
from collections import deque
from time import time

def deque_window(words, search_words, window_len):
    start = time()
    result = []
    pos = 0

    window = deque([], window_len)

    for word in words:
        window.append(word)

        if word in search_words:
            all_found = True
            for search_word in search_words:
                if search_word not in window:
                    all_found = False
                    break

            if all_found:
                result.append(pos)

        pos += 1

    return result, time() - start
```

Actually it took 31 seconds to even calculate the total number of characters and only 48 seconds to find indices which had all words within the search window. I'm not sure if randint or list look-up is really that slow. I'll need a more efficient generator, maybe I'll store the result on disk and try reading it from there (which would be a lot closer to your scenario).

Sum of lengths calculated like this:

```
sum(len(w) for w in words)
```

Comment: I am really interested on this, how could I contact you for a proposal of work on a research paper?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a Open-Source **`Apache Solr`** software for this.

> Apache Solr is the popular, blazing-fast, open source enterprise search
>   platform built on Apache Lucene™

Click on this [link](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for more info. Believe me this provides quick results even for terrabytes of data.